# Blank Page when navigating to SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I created a SharePoint web-application, and a new site collection under it. I made it SSL Enabled. (Now I could view the site and modify/add content). I started modifying the landing page of the sites I created. Basically I created a copy of seattle.master and applied this new css file to my pages. Now suddenly, I see a blank page with no error information, on navigating to my site collection. I tried the LoopBack fix to no avail. I feel this is an authentication issue, but I am unsure where to go from here. Moreover, SharePoint Designer refuses to connect to the site as well (I am getting- SharePoint Foundation not installed on this server error, which is not the case). I have Sharepoint Server 2013, and the web server is on Win Server 2008 R2. Any ideas?

Comment: First thought is missing binding or alternative access mapping for the SSL enabled site. Not enough detail to help any further.

Comment: No, I have bound the certificate with this website. As for AAM, I have both internal and public url set to the same value https://servername. My site is hosted on port 443.

Comment: I kept getting certificate error, (That the certificate belongs to a differently named site or something), but if I proceeded anyway, I could still open my site. (I think, the reason for this certificate error was that the certificate name was my site collection name, not my servername (which is also my site url). Now my question is, does this problem also make the site unusable later, as it did it my case? Is the fix to change the name on the certificate, or to create a DNS entry with the same name on the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my sites on all site collections under a web application.

I tested the other sites in the other site collection and they were coming up ok.

I checked the content database, took it off line and reset it, same issue. Checked log files, no errors in the log files, reset IIS and app pools same issue, checked permissions on the webapp in iis, same issue.

Solution.

Replaced the webconfig from yesterdays backup and it worked,

a solution that was deployed to the web application and activated on the site collection must added some entries and corrupted the file